# VueJS - Show async data in template

Tags: vue.js, asynchronous, async-await

I have this code:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <hot-table licenseKey='non-commercial-and-evaluation' :data="covertDataToTableReadable" colHeaders="true" width="600" height="300">
      <hot-column title="Employee:">
      </hot-column>
      <hot-column title="Date:">
      </hot-column>
      <hot-column title="Project name:">
      </hot-column>
      <hot-column title="Task Link">
      </hot-column>
      <hot-column title="Component">
      </hot-column>
      <hot-column title="Description">
      </hot-column>
      <hot-column title="Time to complete">
      </hot-column>
    </hot-table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'
import { HotTable, HotColumn } from '@handsontable/vue'

export default {
  data: function () {
    return {
      data: [],
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters('projectsPage', {
      headers: 'getTableHeaders',
      filteredTableData: 'getFilteredTableData',
      submitStatus: 'getSubmitStatus'
    }),
    loaded () {
      return this.$store.state.projectsPage__initializedTable
    },
    covertDataToTableReadable () {
      const data = []
      const filteredData = this.filteredTableData.map(item => {
        data.push([item.full_name, item.created_on, item.project_name, item.task_link, item.component_name, item.task_description, item.hours_spent])
      })

      if (data) {
        return data
      }
    }
  },
  components: {
    HotTable,
    HotColumn
  },
  methods: {
    transformAsanaLinkToAtag (asanaLink) {
      if (!asanaLink) {
        asanaLink = ''
      }
      asanaLink = asanaLink.trim()
      let regex = /^https?:\/\/[^\s]+$/g
      if (regex.test(asanaLink)) {
        return '<span><a target="_blank" href=' + asanaLink + '>Task URL</a><i aria-hidden="true" class="v-icon material-icons info--text">open_in_new</i></span>'
      } else {
        return '<span>' + asanaLink + '</span>'
      }
    },
    addClasses (data) {
      let classes = 'default-row'
      if (data.is_billable === 'Yes') {
        classes += ' billable-row'
      }
      if (data.hasOwnProperty('deleted_on') && data.deleted_on !== null) {
        classes += ' deleted-row'
      }
      return classes
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>
  .default-row {
    border-left: 5px solid #808080;
  }

  .billable-row {
    border-left: 5px solid #4caf50;
  }

  .deleted-row {
    border-left: 5px solid #FF0000;
    opacity: 0.3;
  }
</style>
```

I'm some changes to this variable `filteredTableData` in the computed function `covertDataToTableReadable` but in the template, I don't get the data I modified because `filteredTableData` is an observer.

When I console log `filteredTableData` it I get:
`[{…}, __ob__: Observer]`

How can I tell Vue to await the result and then update it in the template?
I would appreciate a more detailed explanation of how it works.

Answer (score 1):

The Observer bit is correct. Don't bother.

I think you're mutating a complex data type `filteredTableData` and Vue is not able to observe this.
Please see https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

In your Vuex mutation you should operate like this:

```
const i = filteredTableData.length;
const someData = { foo: 'bar' };
Vue.set(filteredTableData, i, someData);
```

---

To be clear; Objects and Arrays should not be changed (mutated). The Observer mechanics can not handle the changes correctly.
Changes should be applied by using the `Vue.set()` method.

Answer (score 0):

I've added **if check**(v-if) in the template which shows the renders the template after the data has arrived.

Here is the code:

```
<template>
  <div v-if="filteredTableData.length > 0">
    <hot-table licenseKey='non-commercial-and-evaluation' :data="covertDataToTableReadable" colHeaders="true" width="600" height="300">
      <hot-column title="Employee:">
      </hot-column>
      <hot-column title="Date:">
      </hot-column>
      <hot-column title="Project name:">
      </hot-column>
      <hot-column title="Task Link">
      </hot-column>
      <hot-column title="Component">
      </hot-column>
      <hot-column title="Description">
      </hot-column>
      <hot-column title="Time to complete">
      </hot-column>
    </hot-table>
  </div>
</template>
```

It solved my issue.

The data I'm expecting look like this(array of array):

```
[
   ['', 'Tesla', 'Mercedes', 'Toyota', 'Volvo'],
   ['2019', 10, 11, 12, 13],
   ['2020', 20, 11, 14, 13],
   ['2021', 30, 15, 12, 13]
],
```